# "By now" with the present perfect continuous

Tags: present-perfect, aspect

Recently one of my students has come across a sentence in "Advanced Language Practice" by M.Vince that caused some confusion. The sentence is:

"Nothing much has been happening **by now** / **so far**"

According to the answer key, the correct answer is "so far". While I don't have problems understanding why "so far" is correct in that sentence, I don't really know why exactly "by now" is incorrect. I think I know the meaning of the expression "by now" but still I can't find of any rule or clear explanation of why It should not be used in the above-mentioned context.

Comment: Have you read : http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68345/by-now-vs-now

I think it (by now) implies probability and expectation of something. So, I think in your sentence "so far" is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

'So far' describes the whole period up to and including now. 'By now' is more punctual, it describes the point 'now'. Thus:

'So far' (all the way up until now), nothing has happened, or nothing has been happening.

'By now' (by this point in time called 'now') the mail should have come.